# delete query takes forever

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, delete

I got a reasonable simple query:

```
With RowsToDelete AS
(
    SELECT TOP 500 Id
    FROM ErrorReports
    WHERE IncidentId = 611
)
DELETE FROM RowsToDelete
```

However, it do not complete. I have tried several times. The last time I waited 8 minutes before canceling it.

`ErrorReports` contains about 22 000 rows. `ErrorReportOrigins` about the same.

**Estimated execution plan:**

[image]

**Actual execution plan (for `top 10`, takes 28 seconds to complete):**

[image]

Execution plan: 
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1jUXDruz

**Client stats:**

[image]

What I've tried:

- `ErrorReportOrigins` did not have a clustered index (id), only a FK to `ErrorReports.Id`. I've added an id column (pk&identity).
- I've rebuilt all indexes (using [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2016/07/03/how-to-maintain-azure-sql-indexes-and-statistics/)).
- Tried to delete from `ErrorReportOrigins` first (using the same CTE). No difference
- *(The original CTE had a `ORDER BY Id`, I removed it to see if there was a difference)*

I'm lost. Why on earth does it take so long? All SELECT statements are fast.
And the DB isn't really big. The `ErrorReports` table is the largest one.

*(This is an SQL Azure DB in an elastic pool)*

**Update**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ErrorReports](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IncidentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ErrorId] [varchar](36) NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ReportHashCode] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAtUtc] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SolvedAtUtc] [datetime] NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [RemoteAddress] [varchar](45) NULL,
    [Exception] [ntext] NOT NULL,
    [ContextInfo] [ntext] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

Indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Application_GetWeeklyStats] ON [dbo].[ErrorReports]
(
    [ApplicationId] ASC,
    [CreatedAtUtc] DESC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ErrorReports_IncidentId] ON [dbo].[ErrorReports]
(
    [IncidentId] ASC,
    [CreatedAtUtc] DESC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

The data is fairly large (used `datalength` in the query):

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems likely the very large `ntext` data is highly fragmented, causing a large amount of random I/O (or other inefficiencies) when locating LOB fragments to delete. Maybe the elastic thingy needs more I/O horsepower too.

You may need to export and reload the data to solve this problem. Copying to a new table, dropping the old, then renaming the new would also work.

Unless you have an extremely good reason not to, I suggest you also change the data type from the old, deprecated `ntext` to the replacement `nvarchar(max)` while reloading the data.

It may also simply be a SQL Server limitation with large LOBs. See the related Q & A [Slow Delete's of LOB data in SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/137288).

The usual recommendation is to move to an alternate storage solution when data averages 1MB or more. See the SQL Server technical paper [FILESTREAM Storage in SQL Server 2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh461480.aspx) by Paul S. Randal for details. This is [not yet supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server) in Azure SQL Database, unfortunately.

Perhaps you would be better storing the large LOB data in Azure Blob storage instead, and only holding a link in the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will make a difference but this syntax should work:

```
DELETE TOP (500)
FROM ErrorReports
WHERE IncidentId = 611
```

I tested on a simple table and get a very simple query plan with a single index scan.

Answer (score 0):

IMO ,you should reconsider the size of `[Exception] ,[ContextInfo]` .

for example ,is there any row in table where len(Exception)>1000

I think `varchar(1500)` is enough,it will improve your given query.

May be size cannot altered.

Alternatively you can go for `RBAR`

```
DECLARE @IncidentId INT = 611
DECLARE @TopSize INT = 10 --try 15,20 etc
DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 10 --try 15,20 etc
DECLARE @MaxLimit INT = 500
DECLARE @RowCount INT = 0

BEGIN TRY
    WHILE (@TopSize <= @MaxLimit)
    BEGIN
        DELETE TOP (@TopSize)
        FROM ErrorReports
        WHERE IncidentId = @IncidentId

        SET @RowCount = @@RowCount

        --PRINT @TopSize
        IF (
                @RowCount = 0
                OR @RowCount IS NULL
                )
            BREAK;
        ELSE
            SET @TopSize = @TopSize + @BatchSize
    END
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    --catch error
END CATCH
```