# Remove version ghost records of allocation type LOB_DATA without restarting the service or failing over

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, ghost-cleanup

A database that is part of a SQL Server Always Availability Group with both *synchronous* and *asynchronous* readable secondaries that are being used to scale out read-only workloads is experiencing a build up of version ghost records of allocation type `LOB_DATA`.

This occurs on a table that has a high level of `INSERT` operations applied to it.

`REBUILD`ing the clustered index of this table removes any version ghost records of allocation type `IN_ROW_DATA` but not of allocation type `LOB_DATA`.

Performing a manual fail-over removes the version ghost rows, but this is undesirable.

While I am investigating the root cause of the build up of version ghost rows, is there any other way of removing version ghost records of allocation type `LOB_DATA`?

Comment: Please add the version, edition, and build of SQL Server to your question e.g. SQL Server 2019 Enterprise Edition CU12.. Possibly related Q & A: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137288/slow-deletes-of-lob-data-in-sql-server

Answer (score 6):

Check that ghost cleanup isn't disabled with [trace flag 661](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-traceon-trace-flags-transact-sql).

A query that reads all the LOB data should clean up ghosts if it can.

Ensure you are on the latest build of whichever version of SQL Server you are using. Ghost cleanup bugs are rare these days, but they were prevalent in the past.

You could also try [`sp_clean_db_free_space`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-clean-db-free-space-transact-sql) or [`sp_clean_db_file_free_space`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-clean-db-file-free-space-transact-sql), depending on how your data is arranged.

If none of those things help, you may have encountered a new issue, which ought to be reported to Microsoft Support.